# How to get new files coming into a folder while processing files for the same folder in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

At the beginning of my shell script, I have a FOR loop to scan a folder to see if there is any files there, if yes, I need to process each one of them.  The process for each file would take some time (say a few minutes) depending on how many files are in the folder.

The problem is that: during the processing for each file, there could be new files coming in to the folder, but my tests show that the new files didn't be picked up and processed.  So, is there a way to detect the new files that come in during the processing of the FOR loop ?

I thought about periodically checking the folder for new files, but I don't want to re-process the existing files again, and more ****importantly, since this is only at the beginning of the script, I don't want the FOR loop to repeat too many times.  Thanks.****

```
for aFile in  "$mydir"/*
do
   // some tasks that may take 30 secs or so to finish for each file    
done
```

Comment: Have you thought about re-structuring to use fsnotifywait? I have a bash script sit in an infinite loop, which traps signals. I have another bash script run fsnotifywait on a given directory and send a signal to the other bash script when the right filesystem events happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -xe

# create some dummy files to start with
touch filea
touch fileb

function analyzeFile() {
    echo "analyzing $1"
    sleep 10    # dummy for the real stuff you need to do
}

declare stillGettingSomething
declare -A alreadyAnalyzed

stillGettingSomething=true
while [ $stillGettingSomething ]; do
    stillGettingSomething=false    # prevent endless looping

    for i in ./file*; do
        # idea: see also http://superuser.com/questions/195598/test-if-element-is-in-array-in-bash 

        if [[ ${alreadyAnalyzed[$i]} ]]; then
            echo "$i was already analyzed before; skipping it immediately"
            continue
        fi

        alreadyAnalyzed[$i]=true    # Memorize the file which we visited
        stillGettingSomething=true  # We found some new file; we have to run another scan iteration later on

        analyzeFile $i

        # create some new files for the purpose of demonstration
        echo "creating file $i-latecreate"
        touch $i-latecreate
    done

done
```

The result of this script is

```
+ declare stillGettingSomething
+ declare -A alreadyAnalyzed
+ stillGettingSomething=true
+ '[' true ']'
+ stillGettingSomething=false
+ for i in './file*'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ alreadyAnalyzed[$i]=true
+ stillGettingSomething=true
+ analyzeFile ./filea
+ echo 'analyzing ./filea'
analyzing ./filea
+ sleep 10
+ echo 'creating file ./filea-latecreate'
creating file ./filea-latecreate
+ touch ./filea-latecreate
+ for i in './file*'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ alreadyAnalyzed[$i]=true
+ stillGettingSomething=true
+ analyzeFile ./fileb
+ echo 'analyzing ./fileb'
analyzing ./fileb
+ sleep 10
+ echo 'creating file ./fileb-latecreate'
creating file ./fileb-latecreate
+ touch ./fileb-latecreate
+ '[' true ']'
+ stillGettingSomething=false
+ for i in './file*'
+ [[ -n true ]]
+ echo './filea was already analyzed before; skipping it immediately'
./filea was already analyzed before; skipping it immediately
+ continue
+ for i in './file*'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ alreadyAnalyzed[$i]=true
+ stillGettingSomething=true
+ analyzeFile ./filea-latecreate
+ echo 'analyzing ./filea-latecreate'
analyzing ./filea-latecreate
+ sleep 10
```

The idea behind it is to use an associative array, which memorizes those files already processed. If a file was already processed, it is skipped the next time we step over it. We do this as long as we are getting at least one new file in a scan iteration.

### EDIT: Cleaned-up coding

Here's a cleaned-up variant of the coding above, pruning the demo-purpose coding, trying to come as close as possible to the original requirement.

```
#!/bin/sh

function analyzeFile() {
    echo "analyzing $1"
    sleep 10    # dummy for the real stuff you need to do
}

declare stillGettingSomething
declare -A alreadyAnalyzed

stillGettingSomething=true
while [ $stillGettingSomething ]; do
    stillGettingSomething=false    # prevent endless looping

    for i in "$mydir"/*; do 

        if [[ ${alreadyAnalyzed[$i]} ]]; then
            echo "$i was already analyzed before; skipping it immediately"
            continue
        fi

        alreadyAnalyzed[$i]=true    # Memorize the file which we visited
        stillGettingSomething=true  # We found some new file; we have to run another scan iteration later on

        analyzeFile $i
    done
done
```

Comment: thanks.  but when the while loop will be ended.  To me, it is a indefinite loop.

Comment: It's only an endless loop for the purpose of the demonstration.Just remove the two lines "echo "creating file $i-latecreate" and "touch $i-latecreate" in the loop and it'll work, if you add further files.

Answer (score 1):

this is an interesting problem, and there are many ways to solve it. one way is to keep track somehow of which files are done, then process the first undone file on each loop iteration, e.g.,

```
cd "$mydir"
# make a donedir to put placeholder dummy files
mkdir donedir

while true; do

  # find first file with no corresponding dummy file in donedir
  newfile=`find * -maxdepth 0 -type f |
    sed 's/.*/[ ! -f "../donedir/&" ] \&\& echo "&"/' |
    sh | head -n1`

  # break out of the loop if there aren't any
  [ "$newfile" = "" ] && break

  # do your thing with $newfile...

  # record that you're done with $newfile
  touch "donedir/$newfile"
done
```

a more efficient strategy is to simply move each file to donedir after you're done with it:

```
cd "$mydir"
mkdir donedir

while true; do

  # find first file
  newfile=`find * -maxdepth 0 -type f | head -n1`

  # break out of the loop if there aren't any
  [ "$newfile" = "" ] && break

  # do your thing with $newfile...

  # done with $newfile...
  mv "$newfile" donedir
done
```

one could also keep track of which files are done with e.g., an associative array as [EagleRainbow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6350762/eaglerainbow) suggests, but the disadvantages of that approach are 1. unnecessary complexity, and 2. tracking which files are done isn't automatically preserved across different runs of the script.

Comment: thanks.  but the while loop seems an infinite loop.  As I said, this is only the beginning of the script and I can't have an infinite loop there.

Comment: the `[ "$newfile" = "" ] && break` breaks out of the loop as soon as there are no more new files, and the `# do your thing with $newfile` is the place to do all the processing you need to on each new file.